# GCS ResumableDownload Class

Tags: google-cloud-storage

My business application has requirement to download file from GCS bucket. File size can be in GBs also. Is there any class like ResumableUpload for download? I want to use ResumableDownload, so in case of any interruption in downloading file, it can start downloading for rest of the file.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp#resumable-transfers) of Google Cloud Storage, using the `gsutil` command:

> gsutil automatically performs a resumable upload whenever you use the cp command to upload an object that is larger than 8 MiB. You do not need to specify any special command line options to make this happen. [. . .] Similarly, gsutil automatically performs resumable downloads (using standard HTTP Range GET operations) whenever you use the cp command, unless the destination is a stream. In this case, a partially downloaded temporary file will be visible in the destination directory. Upon completion, the original file is deleted and overwritten with the downloaded contents.

You may find useful this documentation on [Scripting Production Transfers](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/ScriptingProductionTransfers).

Comment: Thanks for your answer Pablo. I would like to know if I can use ResumableDownload functionality using c# program, in case of stream destination. As this class is not available by GCS, is there any other way where I can perform resumable download through program?

Comment: The closest I can think of about this is using the class [MediaDownloader](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/media_download#sample-code), I do not know what kind of downloads, but apart from that there is nothing in official libraries. Perhaps [this blog](https://forums.asp.net/t/1218116.aspx?Resume+Download+for+Huge+Files) may offer some interesting reading in that regard, but it is not related to any GCP specifics.

Answer (score 0):

GCS download methods (both in the XML and the JSON APIs) implement the `Range` header as per [Section 3 of RFC 7233](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233#section-3.1).

This means that, if you know how many bytes you have downloaded, you can start the download again at any point.

Furthermore, you're also able to partially download files. With that, you could even shard the download and then compose the complete file.

An example:

```
BUCKET=<YOUR_BUCKET_ID>
echo "Hello World!">test.txt
gsutil cp test.txt gs://$BUCKET
curl https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/$BUCKET/o/test.txt?alt=media -H'Range: bytes=6-10' -H"Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)"
```

This example should just return the word `World`.

---

Not sure how to implement this in c#, as mentioned in the comment to the other answer, but GCS does support partial downloads. For implementation details, which is more focused on programming, I would suggest you to ask in StackOverflow.